# p:accordionPanel not working with AJAX in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this problem with my according panel. I am trying to use a function that can be triggered whenever I change that tab but the problem is that I am not getting anything. Here is my code. Hope you can help me.

```
<h:form>
    <p:accordionPanel id="layerListAccordionPanel"
                      multiple="true" activeIndex="-1"
                      value="#{CompleterBean.liste}" var="category">

        <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabChange}" />
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabClose}" />

        <p:tab id="layerPanel" title="#{category.date_fin}" closable="true">
            Test
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

and in my bean

```
public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("close");
}

public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("open");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing surely wrong is that you have mistaken the events

```
 <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabChange}" />
 <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabClose}" />
```

should rather be

```
 <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabChange}" />
 <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabClose}" />
```

notice that I've switched events. However, I suspect that this is a typo in your question since this error would not fail silently rather it would break a page upon change. If your backing bean is affecting your view, make sure to have the *update* attribute properly set e.g.

```
 <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabChange}" update=":form" />
 <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{CompleterBean.onTabClose}"  update=":form"/>
```